# how do I keep an assigned object properties when assigning to a base object?

Tags: c#, ruby, generics, object, inheritance

ok Im back with another question... It seems you when you assign base objects as another object , the base object is turned into that object, but still is without its properties for example.

```
public class MyObjectBase {
        public void Begin() {

    }

{
public class OneOfMyObjects : MyObjectBase {
       public void Begin() {
       base.Begin();

   //do stuff

} 
} 
public class ManagmentClass {

public MyObjectBase myCurrentObject;

//called a only one when the program starts
public void Start() {
     Mymethod(new OneOfMyObjects()); 

}
//generic method 
public void Mymethod<T>(T Objectclass) where T : MyObjectBase {
        myObject = Objectclass
        myObject.Begin(); // compiler error, non existent in MyObjectBase 
        myObject.GetType().ToString() //returns "OneOfMyObjects" 

}
}
```

Of course, the compiler can't find "Begin()" since begin doesn't originally exists in MyBaseObject.
I'm doing a conversion between a custom language similar to Ruby to C#(above), but this Ruby-like language doesn't come across this "problem" I'm having. It seems to compile it. Is there something in .NET4 that can solve this issues that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl.  The issue is that you're using a base class that doesn't provide a definition of Begin(and you knew that, just reiterating).  So, the thing to do is to provide a way for the base class to have a Begin() method.  In the below example, MyObjectBase is an abstract class and Begin() is an abstract method.  This means that MyObjectBase will never have a definition for Begin(), but it forces all derived classes to provide a definition for Begin().  So, for example:

```
MyObjectBase obj1 = new MyObjectBase();
obj1.Begin(); //Won't Compile

OneOfMyObjects obj2 = new OneOfMyObjects();
obj2.Begin(); //Compiles if and only if OneOfMyObjects 
//class has a definition for Begin().
```

Also, I'm usually programming in C++ so this may not be 100% best-practice for C#, but it's compile-able.  I also changed the scope of Begin.  Protected is used when you want a derived class to access something in a base class, but it isn't necessarily the scope you use when dealing with something that's derived.  Begin is being accessed from outside of the base and derived classes so it needs to be public.

```
public abstract class MyObjectBase
{
    public abstract void Begin();
}

public class OneOfMyObjects : MyObjectBase
{
    public override void Begin()
    {

        //do stuff

    }
}
public class ManagmentClass
{

    public MyObjectBase myCurrentObject;

    //called a only one when the program starts
    public void Start()
    {
        Mymethod(new OneOfMyObjects());

    }
    //generic method 
    public void Mymethod<T>(T Objectclass) where T : MyObjectBase {
    MyObjectBase myObject = Objectclass;
    myObject.Begin(); // Shouldn't throw an error any more
    myObject.GetType().ToString(); //returns "OneOfMyObjects" 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* just use dynamic typing:

```
dynamic myObject;
```

... but your `Mymethod` method can't *really* accept any instance of a `MyObjectBase`... it *must* have a `Begin` method, for example. Using dynamic typing, you'll only discover when that's not the case at execution time.

Rather than directly porting some code written for a different language with different idioms, you should think about the higher level goal that code is trying to achieve, and the most idiomatic way of achieving the same goal in C#. We can't guide you on that without more information.

Comment: even if MyObjectBase has Begin it wil run begin via MyObjectBase , the code im trying to run is myObject.Begin via OneOfMyObjects.

Comment: @Fornoreason1000: The point is that unless `MyObjectBase` declares a (possibly abstract) `Begin` method, or you change your generic constraint to constrain `T` to also implement some interface with `Begin`, the compiler has no clue whether or not your actual type has a `Begin` method. So either you need to get rid of static typing using `dynamic`, or rethink your approach. I'd advise the latter.

Comment: or i could make an abstract base class of the base class, then override the methods?

Comment: @Fornoreason1000: I don't know what you mean by "make an abstract base class of the base class", and I don't know what the most suitable solution is as we don't have much context.

Comment: "make an abstract base class of the base class", ok write a new abstract base class for MyObjectBase, this way i can keep the methods inside MyObjectBase , and still reference them from OneOfMyObjects . myObject will be an instance of this base class.  I usually would achieve the goal another way but I'm doing this for someone else, and he wants a "clean" port over. thanks for the answer though, I gave you an upvote. I got it to work. thanks for your time

Comment: @Fornoreason1000: But why not just make `MyObjectBase` abstract? Why would you want to add an extra level of inheritance?

Comment: `base.Begin();` will not work if its abstract in `MyObjectBase`, the guy happens to do that very frequenlty.